# Trying to identify PWM IC with marking 1WAU its a SOT23 device

Tags: pwm, identification, sot23

I am trying to identify the device 1WAU which i believe is a PWM buck converter, its driving a BUJ302AD transistor. I have searched on google but no luck in finding this device. If anybody can help in finding this device or an equivalent be much appreciated.

[image]

Comment: "1W" is probably the significant marking code and "AU" a lot code. The point is looking for 1W marking will show parts with 1W power consumption... However the style is similar to this post which refers to a Microchip component: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/574824/help-identifying-this-sot23-6-part-with-cmar-on-top

Comment: Just looked at another one of these IC's and that one has marking 1WAX, looks like you right and AU is a lot code.

I manage to roughly identify what each pin on the IC connected to on the board, power and BJT drive output etc. I have found a device that maybe similar, its made by Renesas part number iW1700-00, could the 1W be actually iW ?

https://www.renesas.com/us/en/document/dst/iw1700-datasheet?r=1563821

Comment: Unfortunately we can clearly see that it is a "1". However could you take a wider photo in order to see more components around? Sometimes it is useful to identify components brands around to guide the research.